# How to retrieve loginProvider name ASP.Net MVC Core for ExternalLoginConfirmation method

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core-mvc

In the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method of the AccountController.cs a new user will be created according to `user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email }`.

I want to create the new user prepending the login provider name in the `UserName` property:

```
user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = provider ?? model.Email + model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

My idea is to try to do like that:

```
var loginProviders = _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();
var provider = loginProviders[index].DisplayName.ToString();
```

How can I select `index` to return the used `loginProvider`?
Unfortunately `var provider = loginProviders.DisplayName.ToString();` does not work.

For Authentication I'm using

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {

        });
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]
        });
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions()
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"]
        });
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"]
        });
```

While testing my web site I use my credential. 
Letting `UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email` turns out to give an error.
I can use the same Email, by setting up

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
            opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        })
```

But I can not have the same `UserName`

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I've found the solution.
In the method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
```

you can get the information about the user from the external login provider by calling

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

You can then add a new user by simply prepending `info.LoginProvider` in the `UserName` field like that

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = info.LoginProvider + model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

Doing that you can use your credentials (you email address) to test multiple login provides avoiding conflics while trying to insert in the `dbo.AspNetUsers` identical `UserName` fields.

Hope it helps!